# How to solve the issue of image size template slider?

Tags: html, slider, carousel

I have a question regarding a carousel slider in a template I recently uploaded on my blog. I downloaded the free ELEGANT template which allows you to have a slider at the top of the page. When you add the tag featured in the post, the blog post will also appear in this slider.

Only thing I don't understand: the images which I have appear different in scale (see attached screenshot) I tried to fix it in the actual image in the blog post, but that doesn't seem to work. Also the HTML code of the carousel is locked, so I cannot change the image sizes there. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? So I can always add my latest blogpost there and all the images have the same size?

I am a basic HTML coder, so I have a little knowledge of coding.

Thanks in advance!

Jorien

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to edit this image so it will be and same proportion as the rest if the images. Also, can you provide the full URL of your site? Maybe we can see something there that could help.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mosh Feu! Here is the link to the website http://bnotesofinspiration.blogspot.nl

Comment: If the image will be fit to the rest of them it will be distorted because of its different proportions a bit. It will matter?